# Azure Blob Storage SDK PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blog storage SDK PHP for performing operation on azure blob.

The SDK is working fine on my local machine. I am able to **create container** and **upload file** to that container.

But when i host the code to AZURE Virtual machine (VM) it is giving me blank page(500 internal server error).

My website is running as sitename.cloudapp.net.

Comment: Does the log show you any error alongside the response?

Comment: I set error_reporting(E_ALL) but it just displays blank page, nothing else.

Comment: I am getting this error PHP Fatal error:  Can't inherit abstract function WindowsAzure\\Common\\Internal\\Authentication\\IAuthScheme::getAuthorizationHeader() (previously declared abstract in WindowsAzure\\Common\\Internal\\Authentication\\StorageAuthScheme) in /var/www/html/azure-sdk-for-php-master/vendor/microsoft/windowsazure/WindowsAzure/Common/Internal/Authentication/StorageAuthScheme.php on line 43